# ClusterIP: None and failing pods

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have an NGINX in front of several PODs, exposed through ClusterIP: none.

NGINX is forwarding traffic to these nodes like that:

```
upstream api {
   server my-api:1066;
}
```

Will this configuration distribute traffic evenly among all PODs behind the `my-api` hostname?
Will failing PODs be removed from the hostname resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default traffic distribution for Kubernetes services is random based on the default [proxy mode: iptables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables).  (This is likely your case)

In very old Kubernetes versions (<1.1) the default [proxy mode: userspace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables) would default to round-robin (you can still switch to that mode if you'd like to)

The newer way (< 1.8) of doing round robin (optionally) is to use [proxy mode: ipvs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs).

You can also look at other solutions like [Cillium](https://cilium.io/) that provide load balancing capabilities.

Comment: Is it wiser to assign fixed clusterip adresses to the pods behind nginx, so NGINX would exclude failed nodes? I am talking about -- upstream api {server my-api:1066;}  (clusterip: none for my-api) -- vs upstream api {server api-ip1:1066;server api-ip2:1066;}

Comment: Not really, because those change as pods come up and down, the service remains constant and it's manage by Kubernetes through endpoints